# What does && mean when used this way, and what is it called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators, logical-operators

I know that it's called logical and but i mean specifically this way of using it,
I was looking at some jsx packages and found this example

```js
const Button = props => (
  <button className={'large' in props && 'large'}>
    {props.children}
    <style jsx>{`button{
      .large {padding: 50px;}
    `}</style>
  </button>
)
```

What does 'large' in props && 'large' mean? I know large is just a class so its irrelevant but can someone put into words what the operator is actually doing?
Is it a short form of some kind of if statement and if so how would you type it out if it wasnt shortened? i hope this makes sense!!

edit: here's another example

```
 <p>{params.categoryName === "rent" ? "rent" : "sale"}</p>
      {loading ? (
        <h1>Loading</h1>
      ) : listings && listings.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <ul>
            {listings.map((listing) => (
              <ListingItem listing={listing.data} id={listing.id} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>No listings for {params.categoryName}</p>
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it clearer written as a ternary ?

`props.includes("large") ? 'large' : '';`

or a good old `if/else` ?

```
if(props.includes("large")){
     return "large";
} else {
     return "";
}
```

`'large' in props` is the same as `props.includes("large")`, it returns a boolean. If the boolean is `true`, then the  next condition is evaluated with "and" (`&&`) . Since a string is truthy (if it has a length), it is returned as the result of the operation, that is, `"large"`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a quick way to say "if x is truthy, return y".

As MDN puts it: "if all values are truthy, the value of the last operand is returned." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#description).

If it wasn't shortened it could look something like this:

```js
x && y;

if(x) {
  return y;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is the logical [AND operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) in javascript. The **logical AND operator** `&&` returns true if both operands are true, and returns false otherwise.

**Example1:**

```
className={'large' in props && 'large'}
```

In the first example, `'large' in props && 'large'` is used as an **Inline If with Logical && Operator** which is equivalent to

```
if('large' in props && 'large'){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

**Example2:**

Similarly, in the second example

```
listings && listings.length > 0
```

which is equivalent to

```
if(listings && listings.length > 0) {
    // display list
}
else {
    // no list error message here
}
```

Hope, this will answer you question.